# I want to open a file with notepad in C++ but how?

Tags: c++

I am trying to open a text file by getting user input.

```
system(topicName.c_str());
```

is not working where topicName is the user input.

Even as a user I am inputting the right name of the file it is not opening with the corresponding file (.txt)

```
 cout << "Intro To C " <<endl; 
 cout << "Intro To C++" <<endl; 
 cout << "Intro To Java " <<endl; 

 cout << "\t\tWhich Topic You Want to edit: ";
 cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
 getline(cin, topicName);

 system(topicName.c_str());
```

Comment: The `system` function runs a program. You most likely won't have a program named `Intro` that takes the arguments `To` and `C` (for example). Assuming you're on Windows (since you mentioned "notepad") please read [this `system` reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx) for more information.

Comment: i see. but it is working while using for example system("topiclist.txt ").
if this is the way it should be then what are other alternatives to get input from user and open the file with the corresponding name??

Comment: Post a [minimal, **complete** verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem. I'm having a hard time seeing the sense in that `ignore` call. You have only one input operation: the line containing the filename followed by a newline. Which means that `ignore` will consume (and live up to its name) up to 1000 chars until the newline (and presumably your file name with it). Thus leaving you staring at a blinking prompt and nothing to show for it. Or are you entering **two** lines in your input? Post a real, *complete*, `main()` that produces your issue.

Comment: @MEHEDIHASAN System can do what the console can do. So simply choose some valid console command and you are fine.

Comment: @WhozCraig it is a prototype of a whole system containing more than 5000 lines. i dont know how to post it here. and if i dont put the ignore call its not asking for the input. i just needed any alternative for opening a file like sytem("fileName.txt") does, where fileName should be from user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you have the following files in the directory in which you are running the program:

[image: File List]

Then, the following code will serve your job:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Intro To C" << endl;
    cout << "Intro To C++" << endl;
    cout << "Intro To Java" << endl;

    string topicName;

    cout << "\t\tWhich Topic You Want to edit: ";
    getline(cin, topicName);

    topicName = "notepad \"" + topicName + "\"";

    system(topicName.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Then upon running, we get the following output:

```
Intro To C
Intro To C++
Intro To Java
        Which Topic You Want to edit: Intro To Java
```

Upon typing this, the file will be opened in notepad if you are running it in a Windows system. Please change your program accordingly if you are using a different operating system.

[image: Output]